# api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll is missing, I can't find this dll on the internet

Tags: c#

I am having problems trying to open a game, demonimated stoneshard, when trying to open I find myself with the following error: "The program cannot be started because api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll is missing on your computer. try reinstalling it to solve this problem." however I know how to solve it, however I could not find this dll anywhere on the internet, and the only ones I found were corrupted, if anyone has information about this dll, I will be grateful to get the solution to this problem.

Comment: Did you ever figured out where to get that dll?

Comment: I have same issue and cant locate this file anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

I would believe this is a place you can install it. https://www.dll-files.com/api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-1.dll.html

Comment: Bruh, is not even the same filename